# Why is it that every other object in my array is blank?

Tags: objective-c, csv, nsstring, nsarray

I read a CSV file into an array using:

```
NSString *theWholeTable = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"example" ofType:@"csv"]
                                                    encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                       error:NULL];
NSArray *tableRows = [theWholeTable componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

And every second object in the array is empty, any idea why?

the CSV file data looks like this:
10,156,326,614,1261,1890,3639,5800,10253,20914
20,107,224,422,867,1299,2501,3986,7047,14374

with 10 and 20 being the start of each new line.

thanks in advance.

***Edit***
I tried using the following code instead:

```
NSArray *tableRows = [theWholeTable componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

And that worked the way I wanted it too.

Although I am still unsure why the newlineCharacterSet created empty objects...

Comment: Is your `CSV` file coming from a Windows computer by any chance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your `CSV` file comes from a non-UNIX system, it may contain multiple line separators (e.g. `\r\n` instead of `\n`). In this case, `componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet` will insert empty strings for empty character sequences between `\r` and `\n`.

You can remove empty strings from `NSArray` using this method:

```
tableRows = [tableRows filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"]];
```

Comment: Ah OK, thanks for the explanation, that makes sense. This particular CSV and then TXT file was created from a simple table using Apple Numbers. I was trying to find something to show me the formatting tags in the file to no avail. And thanks for the predicate tip too, that will come in handy.

Comment: Awesome 1-liner to make Apple's method call behave the way you need it to 90% of the time, thanks.

Comment: I thought the whole reason for using the newLineCharacterSet was so that all line endings were dealt with(windows, apple legacy, linux and intel mac)?? If you know your data is exclusive to one operating system , then you could just use characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n"

Comment: @Miek This is not an issue of the character set being specific to an OS: OP's character set correctly recognizes both `\n` and `\r` as separators, but it treats them as two separators, not one. That's the issue responsible for the problem.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight  Yeah, that's what I meant; I believe the windows eol character is \r\n or visa vesa. What I was trying to say is that the newLineCharacterSet should be taking this into account without creating an empty line. If it can't then it isn't the method I thought it was, and I need to do additional work when parshing.

Answer (score 1):

to solve this problem, I have used other way:

```
NSArray *tableRows = [theWholeTable componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet  characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n"]]
```

So you wouldn't need remove any lines.